# How to prune bitocoind indexes/txindex?

Tags: txindex

In `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` I set `prune=5000`.

That reduced the blockchain size to 5G.

```
du -sch /mnt/btrfs/bitcoind/*
...
5.0G   /mnt/btrfs/bitcoind/blocks
2.8G   /mnt/btrfs/bitcoind/chainstate
17G    /mnt/btrfs/bitcoind/indexes
....
25G    total
```

This is indeed a x10 improvement, before pruning, my bitcoind data directory was roughly 250G. Yet, it's still 25G total. I need to run on a small SD card where there is only 10G of free space.

Now `/mnt/btrfs/bitcoind/indexes/txindex/*.ldb` files take up the majority of space, 17G.

Is there a way to prune the txindex/*.ldb files?

Answer (score 3):

If you have turned off `-txindex` (which should have happened when you enabled pruning), then you can just delete the the `indexes/txindex` folder as it isn't being used.